# Jasmine testing if element fades out

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I have the following two functions that I'm writing some Jasmine tests for:

```
var showSpinner = function () {
    $('#spinner').remove();
    $('<div id="spinner"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-3x fa-fw"></i></div>')
        .appendTo('body')
        .hide()
        .fadeIn();
};

var hideSpinner = function () {
    $('#spinner').fadeOut(function () {
        $(this).remove();
    });
};
```

and my tests are as follows:

```
it('show spinner', function () {
    showSpinner();
    expect($('#spinner').length).toEqual(1);
});

it('hide spinner', function () {
    hideSpinner();
    expect($('#spinner').length).toEqual(0);
});
```

The first test works fine. However due to the `fadeOut` on the `hideSpinner` the second test fails.

I tried to amend it to use a timeout e.g.

```
it('hide spinner', function () {
    hideSpinner();
    setTimeout(function () {
        expect($('#spinner').length).toEqual(0);
    }, 100);
});
```

But that causes the test to pass but with a warning about having no expectations...

How can I test this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read about [Jasmine's Asynchronous Support](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support):

```
it('hide spinner', function(done) {
    hideSpinner();
    setTimeout(function() {
        expect($('#spinner').length).toEqual(0);
        done();
    }, 400);
});
```

`400` ms is the default timeout for [`$.fadeOut`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/#fadeOut-duration-complete).